# IE doesn't recognize TD width?

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I wonder why IE doesn't seem to recognize the width I specify?

Basically I have this code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="right" class="left_frame"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.left_frame {
    background: url(images/side.gif) repeat-y; 
    width: 17px; 
}
```

Even if I add width="17" inside the `<td></td>` tags, the width still doesn't change. This is quite frustrating because the problem seems to be very simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say it's because there's no content in your `<td>`

Try adding a `&nbsp;` in there so the cell has some content, and see how that goes.

Alternatively, placing a `height` on the cell may work as well, depending on your requirements.

Basically the cell is a flat line at the moment, and needs something to tell it how tall it is, in order to draw the background in.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MvBf5/

Comment: +1 Close. No content is required however (see http://jsfiddle.net/MvBf5/8/) what *is* required is some height (something with 0 height is hard to see :-) the `&nbsp;` adds a line of height. In the link I have added it with CSS height explicitly.

Comment: @pst Yep I just posted a height bit 2 secs after you, you were first with the answer though so I'll happily upvote you if you put it in an answer.